# Producing a table that provides counts for @article, @proceedings etc. from a bibtex file

Tags: biblatex, totcount

Is there any way to produce a table that can provide counts based on the @article, @proceedings and other categories in bibtex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  What do you mean by “produce”?  Do you want to insert into a LaTeX document a typeset table showing those statistics?  Or you just need to compile such statistics for your own use?  Please clarify.

Comment: I want to create a macro that will print a table in the final pdf based on what is in my bib file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of entries per entry type can easily be counted in `biblatex`'s `\AtDataInput` hook. The data is then available from the moment the `.bbl` file is read. If you want to count only one specific `\printbibliography` the approach could be similar with `\AtEveryBibitem`.

The code creates a counter for each refsection and type that counts the number of entries of that type in that refsection. A generic counter for each type is defined in terms of the refsection-specific counter for the current refsection.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
% generic counters: typecounter@article, ...
% will throw an error if Biber hasn't been run yet, so I'd avoid them
\def\do#1{%
  \newcounter{typecounter@#1}%
  \csdef{c@typecounter@#1}{%
    \csname typecounter@\the\c@refsection @#1\endcsname}%
}
\abx@doentrytypes

% initialise refsection-specific counters
\def\init@typecounters#1{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \ifltxcounter{typecounter@#1@##1}
      {}
      {\newcounter{typecounter@#1@##1}}}%
  \abx@doentrytypes}

% count entries of each type for this refsection
% \AtDataInput is executed once for every refsection
\AtDataInput{%
  \ifcsundef{@processed@typecounters@\the\c@refsection}
    {\init@typecounters{\the\c@refsection}%
     \global\cslet{@processed@typecounters@\the\c@refsection}\@empty}
    {}%
  \stepcounter{typecounter@\the\c@refsection @\abx@field@entrytype}}

% produce a table
\newcommand*{\bibtypecounttable}{%
  \let\@bibtypecounttable@collector\@empty
  \def\do##1{%
    \ifltxcounter{typecounter@\the\c@refsection @##1}
      {\ifnum\value{typecounter@\the\c@refsection @##1}>0
         \appto\@bibtypecounttable@collector{%
           \ifcsundef{typecounter@name@##1}
             {##1}
             {\csuse{typecounter@name@##1}}
            & \arabic{typecounter@\the\c@refsection @##1}\\}
       \fi}
      {}}
  \abx@doentrytypes
  \ifblank\@bibtypecounttable@collector
    {} 
    {\begin{tabular}{lc}
       \toprule
        Type & Count \\
        \midrule
        \@bibtypecounttable@collector
        \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}}%
}
\makeatother

% custom names for the table can be defined with
% typecounter@name@<entrytype>
\csdef{typecounter@name@article}{Journal articles}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,baez/article,companion}

\printbibliography

\begin{center}
\bibtypecounttable
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: The MWE shows a few citations together with the bibliography. At the end of the document there is a table listing all entry types with at least one entry and their respective entry counts.]

Comment: Works perfectly and it was exactly what I wanted. One thing to note, I got an error related to the use of biber as a backend but that was quickly fixed using 
    \usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

Comment: Subsequent question, how can I define custom names for the type @bibtypecounttable variable? For example, instead of article to manually say Journal article.

Comment: @Michael See the edit. The code show work for both Biber and BibTeX, but you have to run Biber if you have `backend=biber` in the code: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: does the change include how to change the names of the defaults (e.g., article -> journal article).

Comment: @Michael Yes, see `\csdef{typecounter@name@article}{Journal articles}`. You can define `\csdef{typecounter@name@<entrytype>}{<output>}` in the preamble and then `<output>` will be printed instead of the entry type. I could not be bothered to update the image, but the code as posted now should already produce 'journal article'.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much!